# c/c++ qsort/std::sort equivalent in freepascal

Tags: sorting, pascal, freepascal

Was there any built-in sort function to sort an array (of string or of integer) in `freepascal`?

In c/c++ there is std::sort(any_arr) or qsort(any_arr) that can do this..

In Javascript or ruby there is .sort method..

What's in object-pascal?

Comment: any kind of built-in sort is welcome

Comment: There is none for arrays. I ended up writing my own... Or you can use a T(FP)List instead of an array, for lists there are almost 10 different  quicksort implementations built in

Answer (score 1):

Generic functions is a topic currently in the planning stage. Currently most list types (as benibela said) have own sort and customsort options.

Some of the generic container types (like tfpsmap in unit fgl) might have generic sort routines, but usually work with a separate compare function pointer/variable to determine order.

Comment: Meanwhile, there are generic functions in FPC's development version